# How can I convert from a douple loop processing to something better?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

I have the following design:
I have a series of classes that process some objects let's say events.
Each class processes only a specific type of event.
Now when I have these objects/events that need processing I loop over all events and then loop over all the processors until I am done.
The only optimization I did is that if an event is not the proper for a class return immediatelly.
How could I change my design to get rid of this `O(N^2)` loop? Or perhaps it isn't worth changing and it is ok like this?

**Update**
Example algorith-code:

```
for(Event e:events) {  
    for(Processor p:processors) {  
        p.process(e); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could give an example or maybe a little pseudocode or something?  It's hard to tell exactly what you mean.  But if there's anything you can do to avoid `O(N^2)` time, especially if you're gonna end up with a lot of stuff to iterate over, you should at least try.

Comment: observer is what you are looking for i think

Comment: @SamuelReid:Updated OP

Comment: Man, this would be so much easier if Java had pointers.  You could put pointers to the processors in a hash table and then when the event happened, just grab the needed processor.  Assuming I'm understanding your situation correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You could implement the Observer pattern. Each processor would observe the objects and listen for the event. The processor would decide whether or not to handle the event based on what type of event it was.

Java actually has two interfaces explicitly meant for this pattern: [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [`Observer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html).

Comment: What is the difference?In the `Observer` pattern the observable loop over all observers one by one. So this way it seems I would loop over all events over all processors in separate "queues" since I would need different observable per event type. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: @Jim - The theory is that the Observers only subscribe to the specific objects/events that they are interested in. You wind up looping over each registered observer rather than the entire pool of Processors that may or may not be interested. You also don't loop over every Event. The Event only fires when something happens meaning out completely avoid the outer loop.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern  Only the Observers you registered with that event would be notified, so you register your processors with a specific event then call notifyObservers (aka event.notifyObservers()) when you want those specific processors to do their processing. If you had a list of events you could still loop through all the events and call notifyObservers for each event, skipping the need to loop through ALL processors per each event and only hitting the ones you've registered with that event.

Comment: @JustinNiessner:In my case it is not like an event occurs and then the observers should be notified.I have a large batch of events ready for processing. Would it be possible to provide some sample (even pseudo) code taking this fact (the large batch present) into account?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific processor for every event type you can create a Map (EventClass -> EventProcessor) and then you can remove one loop - O(N) now.

Comment: Each processor processes only a specific type of event, not the other way around.